# MongoKitten: check if ObjectId exist

Tags: swift, mongokitten

How to check if ObjectId exist in collection?
From mongo console I do it:

```
> db.collection.find({_id: ObjectId("5bb216a8475fe42644993a40")}, {_id: 1}).limit(1);
```

How to do the same using MongoKitten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let mongoClient = try MongoKitten.Database("mongodb://\(username):\(password)@\(ipAddress)/\(database)")
let myCollection = mongoClient[collection]
let oid = try ObjectId("5bb216a8475fe42644993a41")
let document = try myCollection.findOne("_id" ==  oid)
```

`document` will be `nil` if ObjectId not exist

Also, based on [this](https://blog.serverdensity.com/checking-if-a-document-exists-mongodb-slow-findone-vs-find/) document, `findOne()` method of Mongo DB takes much more resources than `find()` method. But under the hood of MongoKitten `findOne()` uses `find()` method: [link](https://github.com/OpenKitten/MongoKitten/blob/master/4.1/Sources/MongoKitten/Collection/Collection.swift#L246)